How include the mean value in the chart
The code provided below demonstrates how to calculate the mean value for a given set of data directly within an ASP.NET application. I am seeking guidance on how to integrate this calculated mean value into a Chart control by utilizing C# in the backend of the application. I still haven't found the solution.
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource20" runat="server" 
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BuyoffAndMonitoringConnectionString11 %>" 
                                SelectCommand="
                                        WITH NumberedRows AS (
                                        SELECT *, 
                                        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) - 1) / 3 AS GroupNumMean
                                         FROM [DEMUX]
                                          ),
                                 MeanValues AS (
                                         SELECT 
                                            GroupNumMean,
                                            AVG([RX1_Gap1]) AS Mean
                                            FROM NumberedRows
                                            GROUP BY GroupNumMean
                                            )
                                        SELECT 
                                            L.[DateTime],
                                            L.[Shift],
                                            L.[ID_No],
                                            L.[SN],
                                            L.[RX1_Gap1],
                                            L.[RX1_Gap1_Min],
                                            L.[RX1_Gap1_Max],
                                            L.[Result],
                                            ROUND(M.Mean, 4) AS Mean
                                            FROM NumberedRows L
                                            JOIN MeanValues M ON L.GroupNumMean = M.GroupNumMean
                                            ORDER BY L.[DateTime] DESC;"
                                        FilterExpression="Shift Like '%{0}%'">
                                 <FilterParameters>
                             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList14" Name="Shift" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            </FilterParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>

I have tried for the below code
if (dv != null && dv.Count > 0)
{
    DataTable dataTable = dv.ToTable();

    int numberOfValuesToShow = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNumberOfValues.SelectedValue);

    // Group the data by Mean and calculate date ranges
    var meanData = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row["Mean"] != DBNull.Value && float.TryParse(row["Mean"].ToString(), out _))
        .GroupBy(row => Convert.ToSingle(row["Mean"]))
        .Select(grp => new
        {
            Mean= grp.Key,
            StartDate = grp.Min(row => row.Field<DateTime>("TestTimeStamp")),
            EndDate = grp.Max(row => row.Field<DateTime>("TestTimeStamp"))
        })
        .Take(numberOfValuesToShow) // Only take the first 5 groups
        .ToList();

    string[] c = new string[meanData .Count];
    float[] d = new float[meanData .Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < meanData .Count; i++)
    {
        c[i] = meanData [i].StartDate.ToString(); 
        d[i] = meanData [i].Mean;
    }

    Chart8.Series[3].Points.DataBindXY(c, d); // Assuming Series[3] is for Mean
}
if (dv != null && dv.Count > 0)
{
    DataTable dataTable = dv.ToTable();

    int numberOfValuesToShow = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNumberOfValues.SelectedValue);

    // Group the data by Mean and calculate date ranges
    var cpkData = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row["Mean"] != DBNull.Value && float.TryParse(row["Mean"].ToString(), out _))
        .GroupBy(row => Convert.ToSingle(row["Mean"]))
        .Select(grp => new
        {
            Mean= grp.Key,
            StartDate = grp.Min(row => row.Field<DateTime>("TestTimeStamp")),
            EndDate = grp.Max(row => row.Field<DateTime>("TestTimeStamp"))
        })
        .Take(numberOfValuesToShow) // Only take the first 5 groups
        .ToList();

    string[] c = new string[meanData.Count];
    float[] d = new float[meanData.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < meanData .Count; i++)
    {
        c[i] = meanData [i].StartDate.ToString(); // or cpkData[i].EndDate.ToString() depending on your requirement
        d[i] = meanData [i].Mean;
    }

    Chart8.Series[3].Points.DataBindXY(c, d); // Assuming Series[3] is for Mean
}



If you want to integrate the average value calculated by C# into the Chart, you could use network request to integrate it.
You could use Generic Handler (right-click the project->Add->New Item...->Generic Handler) as the backend end. Generic Handler could access and obtain data directly through network requests.
On the front end, you could use Ajax to send network requests to obtain data and draw charts through echart.
The following is a sample program
Assume that your client program is Web Forms in ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework).
Create a Generic Handler, I named it EchartHandler.ashx. The relevant code is as follows.
public class EchartHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var myOption = new MyOption();
        myOption.title = "ECharts";
        myOption.legend = new List<string>() { "MyData" };
        myOption.xAxis = new List<string>() { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD" };
        myOption.series = new List<Series> { 
            new Series() {name = "Data_1",type = "line",data = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6, 7 } },
            new Series() {name = "Data_2",type = "bar",data = new List<int> { 7,6,5,4 } }
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myOption);
        context.Response.Write(json);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


public class MyOption
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<string> legend { get; set; }
    public List<string> xAxis { get; set; }
    public List<Series> series { get; set; } 
}

public class Series
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<int> data { get; set; }
}

Creating a Web Form. The relevant code is as follows
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/echarts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="MyChart" style="width:600px ; height:400px;"></div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/EchartHandler.ashx",
                success: function (data) {
                    //Parse JSON into objects
                    var JsonObjs = eval("(" + data + ")"); 
                    //Constructing a chart
                    var myChart2 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('MyChart'));
                    //Configuration parameters
                    var option = {
                        title: {
                            text: JsonObjs.title
                        },
                        tooltip: {},
                        legend: {
                            data: JsonObjs.legend
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            data: JsonObjs.xAxis
                        },
                        yAxis: {},
                        series: JsonObjs.series
                    };
                    //Using Parameters
                    myChart2.setOption(option);
                },  
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                }
            });  
    </script>

</body>
</html>

Run the project. Now you could access the Web Form through the browser and see the chart drawn with the data provided by EchartHandler.ashx.
Notice:
1.I access data through the url: "/EchartHandler.ashx" path.
2.<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>. The path needs to be adjusted according to the jquery in your Scripts.
3.<script src="Scripts/echarts.min.js"></script>. echarts.min.js needs to be downloaded from the official website and placed in Scripts.

Thank you for replying. But I calculate the mean on the client side, can I still use the generic handler?

@Teh Teh. The generic handler could be used on the client side. I updated the reply and uploaded a sample program. You could use it as a reference.

@Teh Teh. May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?
